# Find out if email address is managed by google

Tags: java, google-api, gmail-api

Suppose I have email address mymail@mycompany.com

I know, that mycompany.com can be managed by google. I.e. my email is still my company domain name, but it's managed via google.

Is there a possibility to find out if email address is managed via google using google api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a DNS lookup for type=MX on your company domain and see if it points to Google?

> $  host -tmx google.com
> google.com mail is handled by 10
>   aspmx.l.google.com. ...

(That is checking who is setup to receive mail for that domain which I believe is exactly what you're asking about but using DNS.)

Comment: I need to check this in code, because I'll need this information further to be used in project. That's why I want o get this info through google api, if possible.

Comment: You can make DNS queries from code and I'd say it's probably faster and more reliable than using a traditional HTTP REST API (for starters it's a single UDP packet and there's no way an HTTP connection can be more efficient than that).  What language are you using, java?    Just doing a quick search: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20dns%20mx%20lookup&es_th=1